# Game Over is not working properly in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am facing three problems right now and i want to get there answer seprately, plz cooperate....

```
import pygame, sys
from random import randint
pygame.init()
screen_size = (350,674)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x_poss = randint(0,350)
y_poss = randint(0,675)
width = 20
height = 20
vel = 8

bases = []
spines = []


red = (255,0,0)

image_1 = pygame.image.load('bird2.png').convert_alpha()
image_2 = pygame.image.load('base.png').convert_alpha()
image_3 = pygame.image.load('base2.png').convert_alpha()
image_4 = pygame.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()

j = 10
isJump = False
jumpCount = j
run = True
base = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height))

def jump():
    global jumpCount, y_poss
    for base in bases:
        if bird.colliderect(base):
            isJump = True
            if jumpCount >= -j:
                y_poss -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                jumpCount = j
                isJump = False

def draw_rect(color, x, y, width, height):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width, height))

def game_over(x,y):
    game_over_font = pygame.font.Font('Omnibus.ttf',40)
    game_over_text = game_over_font.render('GAME OVER', True, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(game_over_text, (x,y))

num_bases = 5
num_spines = 5
is_game_over = False
grav = 1
velo = 2

while len(bases) < 2*num_bases:
    rect = pygame.Rect(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)
    if rect.collidelist(bases) < 0:
        bases.append(rect)

while len(spines) < num_spines:
    rect = pygame.Rect(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), 10, 10)
    if rect.collidelist(spines) < 0:
        spines.append(rect)

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(40)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_poss > vel - width:
        x_poss -= vel

    if key[pygame.K_q]:
        run = False
        sys.exit()

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x_poss < 350 - vel - width:
        x_poss += vel

    if not(isJump):
        if key[pygame.K_UP] and y_poss > vel:
            y_poss -= vel

        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and y_poss < 670 - height - vel:
            y_poss += vel

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y_poss -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    bird = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x_poss, y_poss, width, height))
    spine = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (300,440,10,10))

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    draw_rect((255,255,255),x_poss, y_poss, width, height)
    screen.blit(image_1, bird)

    for spine in spines:
        screen.blit(image_4, spine)
        spine.x += velo
        if spine.x >= 355:
            spine.x = -15
        if spine.colliderect(bird):
            is_game_over = True
            break

    for base_1 in bases[:num_bases]:
        screen.blit(image_2, base_1)
    for base_2 in bases[num_bases:]:
        screen.blit(image_3, base_2)

    for i, base_1 in enumerate(bases[:num_bases]):
        if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
            bases.remove(base_1)
            bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))
            screen.blit(image_2, base_1)

    for i, base_2 in enumerate(bases[num_bases:]):
        if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
            bases.remove(base_2)
            bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))
            screen.blit(image_3, base_2)

    for base_1 in bases[:num_bases]:
        base_1.y += grav
        base_1.x += 0#-1
        if base_1.x == -50:
            base_1.x = 360

        if base_1.y == 675:
            base_1.x = randint(0,360)
            base_1.y = randint(-10, 0)

    for base_2 in bases[num_bases:]:
        base_2.y += grav
        base_2.x += 0#1
        if base_2.x == 360:
            base_2.x = -50

        if base_2.y == 675:
            base_2.x = randint(0,360)
            base_2.y = randint(-10, 0)

    """for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        if base.y - base[i+1].y < 20:
            base.y + (bases[i+1].y - base.y)

    for i, spine in enumerate(spines):
        i += 1
        if spines[i].y - spines[0].y < 20:
            spine.y + (spines[i].y - spine.y)"""

    if is_game_over:
        grav = 0
        velo = 0
        game_over(45, 336)

    jump()

    pygame.display.update()
```

1.First problem, the game over function is not working properly. It's aim is to to when ever bird collide with spine it should display 'Game Over' and every thing must stop....but when i run the code if bird collide it show Game Over till when bird is colliding as the spine move forward it vanishes again...

```
    if spine.colliderect(bird):
            is_game_over = True
            break
```

**I tried something an i came out on.Now whenever bird collide with spines the bases and spines stop but i want to remove my bird image from the screen...**

```
if is_game_over:
        grav = 0
        velo = 0
        game_over(45, 336)
```

**Next two questions will come soon.....Please Stand By and help me.....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you're just telling it to draw the game over then continuing with everything else, you're not stopping the rest of the code from running. How about adding another variable, `is_game_over` then replace your if code with:

```
if spine.colliderect(bird):
    is_game_over = True
    break
```

Then, call game_over, outside the `for` loop:

```
if is_game_over:
    game_over(45, 336)
    continue  # or break, depending on what you're trying to do with game_over
```

Now this way, it should skip the rest of the code so your game stops wit `game_over`. Hopefully this works for you.

Also, why have you defined the `game_over` function inside your `while` loop? This means that it is getting redefined on each loop.

Comment: No problem @Azeem8869786

Comment: Thanks @Rolv Apneseth  Your code worked.